# How to use mongoose pre middleware on bulk insert?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hapi.js

**Scenario :**

- Inserting bulk data via sockets
- using redis as helper to hold data until it's inserted
- using **model.collection.insert** to insert data(bulk) in db

**Query:**

- can we use `pre` middleware in this scenario to put a check over each record before insert/save?

Comment: `model.collection.insert` is directly accessing the native driver, so no. You'd want to use [`insertMany`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) for this, but you'll still only get validation as pre-save middleware isn't supported. So it depends on the sort of "check" you're looking for.

Comment: @JohnnyHK... check is like this :
user can only save data 7 times a day means if he tries to post 8th time it shouldn't be allowed. and also consider above scenario of socket and redis.

Comment: "Model middleware" is supported for the `insertMany` operation (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html). Documentation is non-existent (?) but I think it gets the an array of docs as it's second argument, so like this... `schema.pre('insertMany', function (next, docs) { .. });`